# Magento Overriding Admin Menu

Tags: magento-1.9, menu

I want to override Magento Admin Menu but it does not seem to work.

This is my code:

**app/code/local/Arabnewtech/Adminhtml/config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Arabnewtech_Adminhtml>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Arabnewtech_Adminhtml>
    </modules>

    <!-- Global -->
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <arabnewtech_adminhtml>
                <class>Arabnewtech_Adminhtml_Block</class>
            </arabnewtech_adminhtml>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <page_menu>Arabnewtech_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu</page_menu>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Arabnewtech/Adminhtml/Block/Page/Menu.php**
and this is Menu.php

```
       class Arabnewtech_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu {
    public function foo() {
        return "<h1>foo</h1>";
    }

    public function getMenuLevel($menu, $level = 0) {
        $html = '<ul ' . (!$level ? 'id="nav22"' : '') . '>' . PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($menu as $item) {
            $html .= '<li ' . (!empty($item['children']) ? 'onmouseover="Element.addClassName(this,\'over\')" '
                            . 'onmouseout="Element.removeClassName(this,\'over\')"' : '') . ' class="'
                    . (!$level && !empty($item['active']) ? ' active' : '') . ' '
                    . (!empty($item['children']) ? ' parent' : '')
                    . (!empty($level) && !empty($item['last']) ? ' last' : '')
                    . ' level' . $level . '"> <a href="' . $item['url'] . '" '
                    . (!empty($item['title']) ? 'title="' . $item['title'] . '"' : '') . ' '
                    . (!empty($item['click']) ? 'onclick="' . $item['click'] . '"' : '') . ' class="'
                    . ($level === 0 && !empty($item['active']) ? 'active' : '') . '"><span>'
                    . $this->escapeHtml($item['label']) . '</span></a>' . PHP_EOL;

            if (!empty($item['children'])) {
                $html .= $this->getMenuLevel($item['children'], $level + 1);
            }
            $html .= '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
        }
        $html .= '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;

        return $html;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you create  Arabnewtech_Adminhtml.xml file which module  control file

Comment: i only create config.xml file in app/code/local/Arabnewtech/Adminhtml   if i should create anther file please give me your help and what the file should be